# I'm a prolog newbie and I'm stuck in a program

Tags: prolog

**Goal:**
Apply a loop in the above given code so that it will ask, “Do you want to continue? (Y/ N)”        and then act accordingly. (Hint: make a predicate ‘again/0’ for doing above task).

```
go:-
    write('What is the name of Patient?'), 
    read(Patient),nl, 
    hypo(Patient, Disease), 
    write(Patient),
    write(' probably has '),
    write(Disease),nl. 

go:-  
    write('Sorry I am unable to diagnose the Disease.'),nl.  

hypo(Patient,flu):-  
    sym(Patient,fever),  
    sym(Patient,cough).  
hypo(Patient,headche):-  
    sym(Patient,bodypain).  
sym(Patient,fever):-  
    write(' Does '),
    write(Patient), 
    write(' has fever (y/n)?'),  
    res(R),  R='y'.  
sym(Patient,cough):-  
    write('Does '), 
    write(Patient),
    write(' has cough (y/n)?'),  
    res(R),  R='y'.  
sym(Patient,bodypain):-  
    write('Does '),
    write(Patient),
    write(' has bodypain (y/n)?'),  
    res(R),  R='y'. 
res(R):-  
    read(R),nl.
```

Comment: You forget to pose a question. Are you asking us to do your homework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've given a model with a `go` predicate. The trick is that you get a loop by calling a predicate again recursively if `R='y'` doesn't fail.

```
again :- 
   write('Do you want to continue? (Y/ N)'),  
   res(R),  R='y', 
   go,
   again. 
again :- 
   write('OK, bye'),nl.
```

Comment: Thankyou.:) It worked but in this way. 
  again :- 
    write('Do you want to continue? (Y/ N)'),  
   res(R),  R='y',go, 
   again.